# Cifrado Cesar en python

Tags: python, archivo, cifrado

se supone que debemos hacer un tipo cifrado cesar en python,abriendo un archivo .txt, y su contenido lo tiene que ir recorriendo el caracter 1 lugar (a=b, b=c...z=a), y esto es lo que tengo de código, me pudieran ayudar:

```
mi = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
      'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
mys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
       'M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U','V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
des = 1
opcion = input("Elija una opcion \ne)Encriptar archivo\nd)Desencriptar archivo\n>>: ")
if opcion == 'e':
    nombre = input("Deme el nombre completo y extension del archvo a encriptar ")
    na = open(nombre, 'r')
    caracter = na.read(1)
    cifrado = ""
    while caracter != "":
        if caracter in mi:
            cifrado += mi[(mi.index(caracter) + des % (len(mi)))]
        if caracter in mys:
            cifrado += mys[(mys.index(caracter) + des % (len(mys)))]
        else:
            cifrado = caracter
    print(cifrado)
    caracter = na.read(1)
elif opcion == "d":
    nombre = input("Deme el nombre completo y extension del archvo a desencriptar ")
    na = open(nombre, 'r')
    car = na.read(1)
    descifrado = ""
    while car != "":
        if car in mi:
            descifrado += mi[(mi.index(car) - des % (len(mi)))]
        if car in mys:
            descifrado += mys[(mys.index(car) - des % (len(mys)))]
        else:
            descifrado = car
    print(descifrado)
    car = na.read(1)
na.close()
```

Comment: Hola Bryan, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Cual es el problema exactamente que tienes? ¿Alguna excepción? ¿Que no funciona como esperas?

Comment: hola, a la hora de correrlo, no me imprime los caracteres codificados, de echo, no me imrime nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error principal es que tienes un ciclo `while` infinito a no ser que el archivo esté vacío. Esto se debe a que no actualizas el valor de la variable carácter dentro del `while`, por lo que si el primer valor es diferente de "", el ciclo iterará indefinidamente.

Tienes otro error debido al orden de evaluación de las operaciones, el operador módulo tiene preferencia sobre la suma, por lo que debes agregar un paréntesis que envuelva la suma antes de aplicar el módulo.

El tercer error es las líneas `cifrado = car` y `descifrado = car` del `else`. Esto hace que cuando el carácter no sea una letra definida en las listas la cadena resultante quede vacía. Debe ser en todo caso `cifrado += car` y `descifrado += car`.

En definitiva, podría quedar como:

```
mi = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
      'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
mys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
       'M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U','V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
des = 1
opcion = input("Elija una opcion \ne)Encriptar archivo\nd)Desencriptar archivo\n>>: ")
if opcion == 'e':
    nombre = input("Deme el nombre completo y extension del archvo a encriptar ")
    na = open(nombre, 'r')
    caracter =na.read(1)
    cifrado = ""
    while caracter != "":
        if caracter in mi:
            cifrado += mi[(mi.index(caracter) + des) % len(mi)]
        if caracter in mys:
            cifrado += mys[(mys.index(caracter) + des) % len(mys)]
        else:
            cifrado += caracter
        caracter = na.read(1)
    print(cifrado)

elif opcion == "d":
    nombre = input("Deme el nombre completo y extension del archvo a desencriptar ")
    na = open(nombre, 'r')
    car = na.read(1)
    descifrado = ""
    while car != "":
        if car in mi:
            descifrado += mi[(mi.index(car) - des) % len(mi)]
        if car in mys:
            descifrado += mys[(mys.index(car) - des) % len(mys)]
        else:
            descifrado += car
        car = na.read(1)
    print(descifrado)
na.close()
```

El código se puede refactorizar si lo deseas. Por ejemplo, haciendo uso del nuevo operador de asignación de Python 3.8, de `with` y los métodos `str.lower()`, `str.upper()`, `str.islower()`:

```
LETRAS = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
DES = 1

opcion = input("Elija una opcion \ne)Encriptar archivo\nd)Desencriptar archivo\n>>: ")

if opcion == "e" or opcion == "d":
    des = DES if opcion == "e" else -DES
    nombre = input("Deme el nombre completo y extension del archivo a encriptar ")
    with open(nombre) as archivo:
        res = []
        while caracter:= archivo.read(1):
            c = caracter.lower()
            if c in LETRAS:
                new_c = LETRAS[(LETRAS.index(c) + des) % 27]
                res.append(new_c if caracter.islower() else new_c.upper())
            else:
                res.append(caracter)
        res = "".join(res)
        print(res)
else:
    print("Opción inválida")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, agradezco de antemano el tiempo que te tomaste para aclarar mis errores, eso me ayuda a aprender mas

Answer (score 0):

Puede haber más errores, pero uno claro es que tu aplicación entra en un bucle infinito, la variable `caracter` no varía dentro del bucle `while` por lo que la condición de salida no se cumple nunca, yo probaría a meter la lectura del nuevo caracter dentro del bucle, es decir:

```
while caracter != "":
        if caracter in mi:
            cifrado += mi[(mi.index(caracter) + des % (len(mi)))]
        if caracter in mys:
            cifrado += mys[(mys.index(caracter) + des % (len(mys)))]
        else:
            cifrado = caracter
        caracter = na.read(1)
print(cifrado)
```

Lo mismo aplicaría para el descifrado.