# Letra a Numero Python

Tags: python

necesito ayuda con esto:
Armo un diccionario en python, asignándole a cada letra, un número. Lo que a mí me gustaría hacer es una iteración en la cuál pueda hacer una especie de for loop para que (por ejemplo) al sumarle 3 al número correspondiente de "A", yo pueda pasar una palabra que me devuelva ese nuevo número.
Es decir, no es solo un "characters_items = characters.items()" y pasar letras o números, sino que si puedo hacer una iteración dónde:

- X = Letra
- i = Numero
  Si hago un i + 5
  El nuevo valor de A es F

```html
characters = {'a': 1, 'b':2 ,'c':3 ,'d':4 ,'e': 5,'f': 6,'g': 7,'h': 8,'i': 9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien, lo que quieres hacer es un [Cifrado César](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifrado_C%C3%A9sar). No pones código relevante, así que ayudaré con el concepto.

```
>>> letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> cant_letras = len(letras)
>>> clave = 5 # desplazamiento
>>> letras[(letras.index('a') + clave) % cant_letras] # por ejemplo, con 'a'
f
>>> letras[(letras.index('x') + clave) % cant_letras]
c
```

Se busca el índice del caracter actual `letras.index('a')`, se le suma el desplazamiento `clave`. Finalmente se saca módulo o resto de división entera de esa operación aritmética `% cant_letras`. De esta forma si la suma es mayor que la cantidad de letras, se vuelve a repetir la secuencia desde 0.

Con esa información puedes armar una función y mandarle caracter por caracter de una cadena para codificarla o decodificarla.

Más información al respecto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327378/80870