# Convertir lista de str a int

Tags: python

Tengo que hacer un programa en Python que sume las letras de una palabra.

Se me ocurrió primero definir el valor para todas las letras, luego hacer que se ingrese una palabra, enlistar la palabra para quedar con caracteres individuales, pero no sé cómo puedo transformar (por ejemplo) mi 'A' = A = 1, o convertir mi lista de str en int.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Debes mostrar lo que has intentado. En todo caso te doy una pista: cada caracter impreso ('A', 'B', etc.) tiene asociado un valor entero de acuerdo a la tabla ASCII de caracteres. En Python puedes obtener este valor entero usando el método `ord()`, por ejemplo: `valor_de_A = ord('A')`. Si estudias bien la tabla ASCII y el método `ord()`, seguro darás con una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. ¿Estas tratando de hacer un [Cifrado Cesar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327352/cifrado-cesar-en-python)?

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser que lo que busques sea esto???

```
palabra = "supercalifragilisticoespialidoso"


resultado = 0
for caracter in palabra: 
    resultado = resultado +  ord(caracter) - ord('a') + 1 

print( resultado )
```

El problema que puede tener esta solución son las marcas diacríticas (los acentos) que tienen un valor diferente del caracter `ord("á") != ord("a")`. Lo mismo ocurre con los caracteres nacionales (eñe no tiene un lugar "correcto" dentro del alfabeto.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es a cada letra asignarles un valor especifico que tu quieras puedes usar un diccionario, por que este te permite al almacenar mediante una clave un valor. Para este caso la clave seria la letra y el valor el numero que quieres que represente, por ejemplo seria así:

```
valores_letras = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'R':3, 'U':4, 'E':5, 'P':6}
```

Yo utilice esas letras por el string que voy a usar, pero tu deberías hacer esto con todo el abecedario, es decir, en el diccionario colocar todas las letras del abecedario con un valor que tu quieras. Como ves `'A'` es la clave y `1` su valor, para obtener este 1 solo basta colocar `valores_letras['A']` (ten cuidado con las claves por que son sensibles, si colocas `'a'` no te dará el valor que guarda).

Entonces lo que te conviene haces es recibir un string y pasar una lista de caracteres individuales:

```
string_de_prueba = list("PRUEBA")
```

Esto te devolverá una lista así `['P', 'R', 'U', 'E', 'B', 'A']`, con esta lista puedes realizar una iteración sobre ella y pasarle al diccionario cada letra para que te devuelva el valor numérico que le asignaste y ir sumándolos e guardándolos en una variable.

```
 suma_valores_letras = 0
 for letra in string_de_prueba:
     suma_valores_letras += valores_letras[letra]
```

Y el resultado para este ejemplo guardado en la variable `suma_valores_letras` es `21`